# Why carrom coins have the circular profiles on them?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, solid-mechanics, friction

[image]

Why do carrom coins have these circular profiles on them? At first I thought that this will reduce the friction as area reduces, but quickly recalled that friction for solids don't really depend that much on area, and in this case that change will be negligible. Is there any physical significance to making these profiles? Why can't we just make them smooth?

Comment: Isn't the [striker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom#Strikers) flat ? Also, please crop the photo to include the picture of the just the coins (and provide necessary attribution below it)

Comment: The [rules](http://www.indiancarrom.co.in/laws-of-carrom/) specify thickness, diameter, and mass, allowing a variation of only .25 grams in mass. Depending on the density of the wood, you may need to remove some to maintain the minimum size without exceeding the maximum weight/mass. Even if it's not strictly necessary, I can see where somebody might prefer a larger size (but obviously still can't exceed maximum weight).